# Can't run mssql docker image: permissions_check.sh: exec format error

Tags: sql-server, linux, docker, docker-compose, raspberry-pi

I've trying to run a mssql docker container with Linux 20.04 installed in a Raspberry pi, and I got the following error:

```
mssql            | exec /opt/mssql/bin/permissions_check.sh: exec format error
mssql exited with code 1
```

My docker compose file is the following:

```
version: "3.7"
services:

  sql-server-db:
    container_name: mssql
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
    #image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CU18-ubuntu-20.04
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    environment:
      MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD: ******
      ACCEPT_EULA: Y
    volumes:
      - ./Data/mssql:/var/opt/mssql/data
```

Also, I've tried to run the container like this:

```
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=******" -p 1433:1433 --name mssql -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CU18-ubuntu-20.04
```

Additionally, I've tried more than one image with no success.

I've tried everything I have in my hands, I'm starting to losing my mind with this right now....

Things I've tried:

- I read an article in stackoverflow about defining a volume inside docker-compose.yml file to the mssql image.
- I've put and take single and double quotation marks from the docker-compose.yml file.
- As I mentioned before, I tried to run docker run (...) command to check another way around.

I expected these to work since I thought I had a spelling mistake or a comma, quatation mark wrong, etc. All with no success.

Comment: Have you tried single-quotes instead of double-quotes on the `docker run` command line?

Comment: Yes Dan, I've tried with simple and double quotations with no success

Comment: [`mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server`](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) isn't supported on ARM microarchitecture, how did `docker-compose` even start a container for it on a Raspberry Pi? If you need an SQL Server-like function consider using the lesser featured Azure SQL Edge, which does support the ARM microarchitecture, [`mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge`](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-azure-sql-edge).

Comment: Nice!, thanks!, it runs the container now, but I have the following error: WARNING: Failed to connect to SQL because: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:1431: connect: connection refused, will reattempt connection, eventhough I have in the docker-compose file 1433:1433, is that warning something internal of docker?, because I can't connect either...

Comment: I can't connect now, but the error is still there, I've search for it, found something about extra hosts, adding host.docker.internal to the docker-compose file, but it didn't work either.

Comment: `127.0.0.1:1431` is trying to connect to TCP port 1431. If you have `1433:1433` in your docker-compose.yml then Docker should be exposing the container's port 1433 on the host's port 1433. Try using port 1433. If you're trying to connect between containers (such as from an app container) use the container name instead, i.e.: `mssql:1433`.